Learning during the Leader's Repetition of the Amidah - sources that permit it?
The sources are clear that one should not learn Torah during the Leader's Repetition of the Amidah.
See Halichipedia

It is improper to learn Torah or say other parts of davening during
Chazarat Hashatz.[17]

The Mishnah Berurah O CH 124 MB 17 expresses it so:

(יז) ולכוין - ע"כ יש ליזהר מלומר תחנונים או ללמוד בעת חזרת הש"ץ ואפילו
אם מכוונים לסוף הברכה לענות אמן כראוי שלא תהיה אמן יתומה כמו שיתבאר
ג"כ לא יפה הם עושים שאם הלומדים יפנו ללימודם עמי הארץ ילמדו מהן שלא
להאזין לש"ץ ויעסקו בשיחה בטילה ח"ו נמצאו מחטיאין את הרבים:
"(17) And to focus - Therefore, one must be careful not to say
supplications or study during the repetition of the Amidah by the
prayer leader, even if they intend to respond 'Amen' at the end of the
blessing properly so that it will not be an 'orphaned Amen,' as will
be explained. It is also not appropriate because if those who are
studying turn to their studies, the unlearned will learn from them not
to listen to the prayer leader and will engage in idle chatter, God
forbid. Thus, they cause many to sin."

This is the answer to the question Can you learn during chazarat hashatz?.
My question is that I observe that many people ignore this teaching. I wonder do they have any sources on whom to rely?

Check out OC 68

I once heard a prominent Rosh Yeshiva admit this was a bad habit of his that he couldn't break.

I saw Kaf Hachayim has very strong language about this.

Also the Alter Rebbe's siddur: ואם אין ט' מכוונים לברכותיו קרוב להיות ברכותיו לבטלה... ויש לגעור באנשים שלומדים בעת חזרת הש"ץ

possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29161/759

There's a leniency often cited here, but it's frowned upon by most poskim.

The question cited by Deutronomy does has an answer that addresses you question. See the answer that brings the Rema Mepano
