# Answering Amen , Barachu and the like outside of a Minyan

Tags: minyan, amen

If one is neither in the room of a *Minyan* nor part of it  , but can hear it and see it , may he answer Amen, Barachu and the like

Comment: What's "the like"?

Comment: Really everything that the tzibbur answers to

Comment: See [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12960/5) to another question.