# Answering the Chazzan from outside a Shul

Tags: tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, kaddish, minyan, amen

If one is neither part of a certain *Minyan* nor *Davening* at all rather in a different room, but can hear the *Chazzan*, may he answer to *Amen,Kaddish*,etc. ?

Comment: Hi. Why might one think he can't answer such that you have this question? He heard it. Please [edit] to clarify and add motivation to your question so others will become more interested.

Comment: When I was in Ge'ula (in Yerushalayim) I went to a bookstore right next to a minyan factory. The bookstore stood and responded for Kedushah, so I followed suit.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I think you mean, **the people in the**  bookstore. I can't recall the last time I saw a bookstore say Kedusha :-)

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3974 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12956

Comment: @DanF, whoops, typo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 15:4 - סימן טו - דיני קדיש וברכו וצרוף עשרה ואם יצאו מקצתן ודין השליח צבור](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0014_L2)

> צְרִיכִין שֶׁיִּהְיוּ כָּל הָעֲשָׂרָה בְּמָקוֹם אֶחָד, וְהַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר עִמָּהֶם, אֲבָל אִם מִקְּצָתָם בְּחֶדֶר זֶה וּמִקְּצָתָם בְּחֶדֶר אַחֵר, אֵינָם מִצְטָרְפִין, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁהַפֶּתַח פָּתוּחַ בֵּינֵיהֶם, וַאֲפִלּוּ אִם הָרֹב הֵמָּה בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת, וְהַמִּעוּט בַּעֲזָרָה שֶׁלִּפְנֵי בֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת, אֵינָם נִגְרָרִים אַחַר הָרֹב לְהִצְטָרֵף עִמָּהֶם וַאֲפִלּוּ הָעוֹמְדִים עַל הָאַסְקֻפָּה בְּתוֹךְ הַפֶּתַח מִן הָאֲגַף וְלַחוּץ. דְּהַיְנוּ, כְּשֶׁסּוֹגְרִין אֵת הַדֶּלֶת, נִמְצָא מָקוֹם זֶה לַחוּץ, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁעַתָּה הַפֶּתַח פָּתוּחַ, מִכָּל מָקוֹם נִדּוֹן כְּלַחוּץ, וְכָל זֹאת לְעִנְיַן צֵרוּף לַעֲשָׂרָה אֲבָל **אִם הָיוּ כָּאן עֲשָׂרָה, וְאוֹמְרִים קַדִּישׁ אוֹ בָּרְכוּ אוֹ קְדֻשָּׁה, אֲזַי כָּל הַשּׁוֹמֵעַ קוֹלָם, יָכוֹל לַעֲנֹת עִמָּהֶם, אֲפִלּוּ כַּמָּה בָּתִּים מַפְסִיקִים בֵּינֵיהֶם, כִּי אֲפִלּוּ מְחִיצָה שֶׁל בַּרְזֶל, אֵינָהּ מַפְסֶקֶת בֵּין יִשְֹרָאֵל לַאֲבִיהֶם שֶׁבַּשָּׁמַיִם, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁלֹּא תְּהֵא שָׁם צוֹאָה אוֹ עֲבוֹדַת גְּלִילִים.** (נ"ה) ‏

If one can hear the Chazzan, one may answer Amen, Kaddish, Borch or Kedusha - no matter how far away one is - on condition that there's no excrement or idols (churches?) between oneself and the Chazzan.

Comment: This became an interesting question at the Daf Yomi siyum IIRC, since the majority of individuals were hearing a havarah/reproduction of the mevarech and not the mevarech himself. I don't recall the resolution of the shailah, but it had interesting ramifications regarding recorded music...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky Are you referring to the last Daf Yomi gathering in NJ?

Comment: @DanF Actually, even before that - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siyum_HaShas#11th_Siyum_HaShas The 11th was held in Madison Square Garden when I was in college.